# Nodejs : get the name and value of Object passing from frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, microservices

I am developing a **microservice** by using **nodejs**.

request is getting following **JSON**.

```
{
     "distCd": "abcd",
     "distName": "parentLife Distributor (TOD)",
     "stateCd": "",
     "subdistInd": false,
     "maindistInd": true,
     "maindistCd": "",
     "distOpendt": "2018-08-28T17:36:02Z",
     "pricegrpCd": "01",
     "costPricegrpCd": "",
     "rssInd": false,
     "branchInd": false,
     "taxregionCd": "",
     "octroiInd": false
}
```

How can I get the name like "distCd" and the value "abcd"

Comment: How are you sending data from front end to back end? By ajax or form submit?

Comment: What is you framework/stack you use in back end side?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.` notation to access individual properties

```js
var a={
                "distCd": "abcd",
                "distName": "parentLife Distributor (TOD)",
                "stateCd": "",
                "subdistInd": false,
                "maindistInd": true,
                "maindistCd": "",
                "distOpendt": "2018-08-28T17:36:02Z",
                "pricegrpCd": "01",
                "costPricegrpCd": "",
                "rssInd": false,
                "branchInd": false,
                "taxregionCd": "",
                "octroiInd": false
};
console.log(a.distCd)
```

Additionally the properties can also be accessed using `[]`

```js
var a={
                "distCd": "abcd",
                "distName": "parentLife Distributor (TOD)",
                "stateCd": "",
                "subdistInd": false,
                "maindistInd": true,
                "maindistCd": "",
                "distOpendt": "2018-08-28T17:36:02Z",
                "pricegrpCd": "01",
                "costPricegrpCd": "",
                "rssInd": false,
                "branchInd": false,
                "taxregionCd": "",
                "octroiInd": false
};
console.log(a["distCd"])
```

For Getting the property names i.e. the **keys** you can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). This will give us an array of all the keys present in the object.

```js
 var a={
                "distCd": "abcd",
                "distName": "parentLife Distributor (TOD)",
                "stateCd": "",
                "subdistInd": false,
                "maindistInd": true,
                "maindistCd": "",
                "distOpendt": "2018-08-28T17:36:02Z",
                "pricegrpCd": "01",
                "costPricegrpCd": "",
                "rssInd": false,
                "branchInd": false,
                "taxregionCd": "",
                "octroiInd": false
};
console.log(Object.keys(a))
console.log(Object.keys(a)[0]) //to access the first key
```

To get all the values in the object, you can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).  This will give us an array of all the values present in the object.

```js
var a={
                    "distCd": "abcd",
                    "distName": "parentLife Distributor (TOD)",
                    "stateCd": "",
                    "subdistInd": false,
                    "maindistInd": true,
                    "maindistCd": "",
                    "distOpendt": "2018-08-28T17:36:02Z",
                    "pricegrpCd": "01",
                    "costPricegrpCd": "",
                    "rssInd": false,
                    "branchInd": false,
                    "taxregionCd": "",
                    "octroiInd": false
    };
    console.log(Object.values(a))
    console.log(Object.values(a)[0]) //to access the first value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), or just [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

Comment: It helps me alot. This is what I am looking for